# Conditional Formatting Issues

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, highlight

I have a series of rows in Excel. I would like to highlight certain rows as different colors depending on the value in a particular cell.

[Example Excel Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le7QI.png)

In this data, I would like to highlight any row that DOES NOT contain a None in the E cells.

I try the following rule:

[Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE5rQ.png)

It doesn't actually highlight the row and I am not sure what to do to remedy the issue.

Thank you,

Comment: Put the `None` in quotes `"None"` in your formula. so your formula should be `=$E2<>"None"`

Comment: @ScottCraner - thank you! What if I wanted to do it for the entire E column?

Comment: You would need the "applies to" `=Sheet1!A:W` with the rule formula: `$E1<>"none"` (but this would also highlight all empty rows)

Comment: The formula is the same you just change the Applies To: to cover the entire range,  I would avoid using the entire column but start with row 2 as your 1st row is headers.  So I would use `Sheet1!$A$2:$W$1000000` for your applies to: and keep the formula the same as I have in my last comment.  And As @DirkReichel just pointed out this will highlight the blank rows at the bottom.  So it may be better to do just the used portion.

Comment: At best check for the cell to not be empty and then just use the range like @scottcraner suggested... the formula: `=($E2<>"None")*LEN($E2)`